# How to add scrollable tabs with a pinned header within a DraggableScrollableSheet?

Tags: flutter, tabs, nestedscrollview

I'm trying to use a `NestedScrollView` for scrollable tabs within a `DraggableScrollableSheet` and need to pass the sheet's controller to the `NestedScrollView`'s scrollable body, however doing so is not supported by `NestedScrollView` which requires that inner scrollables implicitly use the context's `PrimaryScrollController`.

The resultant behaviour is that I am seeing:

1. The draggable sheet behaviour is correct and the sheet moves up before scrolling but the header's elevation is not applied once scrolling nor is the header responding to drag events ("Foo" tab below), OR;
2. The inverse of the above - the sheet does not respond to drag events but the header's elevation is correctly applied and the header itself correctly responds to gestures for scrolling ("Bar" tab below)

[image: Screen-Recording-2020-12-06-at-5.35.01-pm.gif]

I've tried a multiple combinations of `NestedScrollView`, `CustomScrollView`, and `TabView`, tried adding the controller to all, some, none of the scrollables. No luck. I have even tried listening to `Notification` events from either attached scrollable and update the other one with those events to try to keep them in sync. Nada.

Would appreciate any and all help on this, I've been tearing my hair out for a while now. Thank you!

Here's the code for `main.dart` in the video above:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        initialChildSize: 0.6,
        maxChildSize: 0.9,
        minChildSize: 0.6,
        builder: (context, scrollController) => DefaultTabController(
          length: 2,
          child: _buildNestedScrollView(scrollController),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  NestedScrollView _buildNestedScrollView(ScrollController scrollController) {
    return NestedScrollView(
      // controller: scrollController,
      headerSliverBuilder: (context, innerBoxIsScrolled) {
        print('innerBoxIsScrolled $innerBoxIsScrolled');
        return [
          SliverOverlapAbsorber(
            handle: NestedScrollView.sliverOverlapAbsorberHandleFor(context),
            sliver: SliverAppBar(
              toolbarHeight: 0.0,
              pinned: true,
              primary: false,
              forceElevated: innerBoxIsScrolled,
              bottom: TabBar(
                tabs: [
                  Tab(text: 'Foo'),
                  Tab(text: 'Bar'),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ];
      },
      body: TabBarView(
        children: [
          ListView.builder(
            controller: scrollController,
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
              color: Colors.primaries[index % 10],
              height: 150.0,
            ),
          ),
          ListView.builder(
            // controller: scrollController,
            physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
            padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
              color: Colors.primaries[index % 10],
              height: 25.0,
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Relevant links:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ScrollableWidgetBuilder.html

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/NestedScrollView/body.html

[Potentially relevant Flutter issue.](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/64157)

Comment: Have you succeed on solving this issue? I am also struggling with NestedScrollView

Comment: Unfortunately not @RaulMabe (and apologies for the late reply). I'd suggest up-voting the Flutter issue above to register more interest for a resolution by the Flutter team.

Comment: Excuse my lack of comprehension, but I have failed to understand what is the expected behavior. Also, are you still looking for a solution?

Answer (score 0):

smart solution

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      body: SizedBox.expand(
        child: DraggableScrollableSheet(
          initialChildSize: 0.6,
          maxChildSize: 0.9,
          minChildSize: 0.6,
          builder: (context, scrollController) => DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            child: SafeArea(
                child: Column(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: [
                SingleChildScrollView(
                  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                  controller: scrollController,
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: const TabBar(tabs: [
                      Tab(text: 'Foo'),
                      Tab(text: 'Bar'),
                    ]),
                  ),
                ),
                Expanded(
                  child: TabBarView(
                    children: [
                      ListView.builder(
                        controller: scrollController,
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                          color: Colors.primaries[index % 10],
                          height: 150.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      ListView.builder(
                        // controller: scrollController,
                        physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
                        padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
                          color: Colors.primaries[index % 10],
                          height: 25.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                )
              ],
            )),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]